# Spark Streaming: Average of all the time

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, dstream, atomic-long

I wrote a Spark Streaming application which receives temperature values and calculates the average temperature of all time. For that i used the `JavaPairDStream.updateStateByKey` transaction to calculate it per device (separated by the Pair's key). For state tracking I use the `StatCounter` class, which holds all temperature values as doubles and re-calculates the average each stream via calling the `StatCounter.mean` method. Here my program:

**EDITED MY WHOLE CODE: NOW USING StatCounter**

```
JavaStreamingContext streamingContext = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(1));

streamingContext.checkpoint("hdfs://server:8020/spark-history/checkpointing");

JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> ingoingStream = streamingContext.socketTextStream(serverIp, 11833);

JavaDStream<SensorData> sensorDStream = ingoingStream.map(new Function<String, SensorData>() {
    public SensorData call(String json) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        return (SensorData)om.readValue(json, SensorData.class);
    }
});

JavaPairDStream<String, Float> temperatureDStream = sensorDStream.mapToPair(new PairFunction<SensorData, String, Float>() {
    public Tuple2<String, Float> call(SensorData sensorData) throws Exception {
        return new Tuple2<String, Float>(sensorData.getIdSensor(), sensorData.getValTemp());
    }
});

JavaPairDStream<String, StatCounter> statCounterDStream = temperatureDStream.updateStateByKey(new Function2<List<Float>, Optional<StatCounter>, Optional<StatCounter>>() {
    public Optional<StatCounter> call(List<Float> newTemperatures, Optional<StatCounter> statsYet) throws Exception {
        StatCounter stats = statsYet.or(new StatCounter());

        for(float temp : newTemperatures) {
            stats.merge(temp);
        }

        return Optional.of(stats);
    }
});

JavaPairDStream<String, Double> avgTemperatureDStream = statCounterDStream.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Tuple2<String,StatCounter>, String, Double>() {
    public Tuple2<String, Double> call(Tuple2<String, StatCounter> statCounterTuple) throws Exception {
        String key = statCounterTuple._1();
        double avgValue = statCounterTuple._2().mean();

        return new Tuple2<String, Double>(key, avgValue);
    }
});

avgTemperatureDStream.print();
```

This seems to work fine. But now to the question:

I just found an example online which also shows how to calculate a average of all time here: https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-reference-applications/content/logs_analyzer/chapter1/total.html

They use `AtmoicLongs` etc. for storing the "stateful values" and update them in a `forEachRDD` method.

My question now is: What is the better solution for a stateful calculation of all time in Spark Streaming? Are there any advantages / disadvantages of using one or the other way? Thank you!

Comment: Which spark version are you using?

Comment: Any reason you're splitting `JavaPairDStream<String, SensorData>` into two DStreams? Why not use `reduceByKey` to aggregate all data for a specific sensor?

Comment: I separated them because I need one PairDStream for the sum and one for the count to be able to re-calculate the average after every batch-interval. I aggregate each PairDStream (sum & count) by reduceByKey... Ah and I splitted them because SensorData is a class for storing some more things than only the temperature value. So I needed to split into Float & Long streams

Comment: Why do you need one for the sum and one for the count, why not calculate both inside the stateful stream?

Comment: Why compute sum at all instead of using streaming average?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov can you make an example e.g. code snippet or give me an url of an example? Or shall I add all my code for evaluation?

Comment: @zero323 You mean calculating average only within the batch or window? I don't do it because I want to test a all-time calculation.

Comment: No. My point is sum / count has very poor numerical properties. You can use  Knuth streaming average.

Comment: @zero323 you mean an algorihm like this: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/average-of-a-stream-of-numbers/ which needs only oldAvg, count and newValue?

Comment: Pretty much. It is already implemented in [StatCounter](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/5eef1e6c6a8b6202fc6db4a90c4caab5169e86c6/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/StatCounter.scala#L30)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116108/discussion-between-d-muller-and-zero323).

Comment: Now edited my code with usage of StatCounter, thank you for the info, @zero323! Can now someone give an explanation which variant is better (AtomicLongs, Atomic... VS StatCounter)?